# Selenium IDE - unable to detect end of update panel

Tags: selenium-ide

We're using Selenium IDE to automate (record and playback) of test cases.

Many of the actions we need to automate use "Update panel" to alter the pages.

When controls are added or removed, I'm able to detect the end of the "update panel" (waitForElementPresent, waitForElementNotPresent).

One test case is testing when an update only changes some control attributes (e.g. the items in a drop-down list - are more than often, we can't predict what the new contents will be).

How can I find a way to detect the end of the update panel with only Selenium IDE and not the Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **waitForPageToLoad**?

Comment: You could also look for a CSS element to be present?